# Is LINQ Except method doing a Distinct before comparing the two dataset?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I need to list the values from a list that are not contained in another list. I'm currently using LINQ `Except` method.

For example

```
// list1 values: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9]
// list2 values: [7, 8, 9, 10]
list1.Except(list2);
// result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Since I'll have to run the Except against lists with more than 500k records, should I do a `Distinct()` before or is that something already done by the `Except()` itself?

```
list1.Distinct().Except(list2);
```

Is it better, performance wise? I wasn't able to find any reference on this on the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-7.0). Am I blind?

Thank you

---

EDIT

I don't need to further modify the except list after it has been calculated, I just need the list of items from list1 that are not in list2.
My concerns are mainly on the performances, since I'll use huge lists to compare.

Comment: How can we answer that? Maybe removing duplicates is against the business logic? If that is list of items ordered and you then count then you just made sure every count returns 1.

Comment: sorry @TomTom I don't understand your question. Business logics on my side? if so, It's fine removing duplicates. If you meant in general, I think it's fine to remove duplicates since except should return what's not inside the second set, regardless we have or not duplicates in the first one. Am I wrong?

Comment: Except when the next step requires the duplicates to be present in the first place and you just removed them. if your task is to remove all elements in list 2, then a district is not fulfilling the task - it is making a further removal of information.

Comment: No, you don't need `Distinct` since `Except` is a set based method, which is always ignoring duplicates. If all elements in list2 are always unique it would be better to store them in a `HashSet<int>`, then `Except` would also be more efficient, because the `HashSet<T>` constructor [is optimized](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,d0822f25708256c5) for that case.

Comment: If you need to modify the list further then it might be better to use your own `HashSet` like `var set = new HashSet<int>(list1); set.ExceptWith(list2);`

Comment: @tomtom Except returns a distinct set of values already, my question is if I need to do Distinct on the source list (list1), not on the output.

Comment: If performance is your concern, Linq is not going to help anyway. With or without except, you get same results, and not going to save any meaningful iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do any `Distinct()` call; As we can see from the [reference code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e289e6c98881b2b8)

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, 
                                                    IEnumerable<TSource> second, 
                                                    IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer) {
    Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in second) set.Add(element);
    foreach (TSource element in first)
        if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;
}
```

.Net build a `set` from `second` enumeration and then scan `first`. We have `O(m + n)` time complexity: `O(m)` to build `set` from `first` and then `O(n)` to scan.

If you add `Distinct()` you'll get `O(n)` for distinct, then `O(m)` to build `set` and, finally, `O(1) .. O(n)` to scan = `O(n) + O(m) + O(1 .. n) = O(m + n)`. So far so good the same complexity with extra `Distinct` operation.